# Why is a ragtail an annoying person?

Tags: etymology, slang

I've heard an annoying person referred to as a ragtail and I've found a reference to the word below; however, I'm uncertain of the etymology. I'm curious to know why a ragtail is an annoying person. Any ideas?

http://books.google.com/books?id=DsFIAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=ragtail+an+annoying+person&source=bl&ots=vQb-bE9SEa&sig=sEpvDaVHBW9zz4fkmSj0z7w77qc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2LeUU57iK4iQqgbVrYCYBQ&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ragtail%20an%20annoying%20person&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that '*[ragtail](http://www.seadict.com/en/en/ragtail)'* is a term formed from the fusion of the two words of the expression: *[ragtag and bobtail](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ragtag%20and%20bobtail),*

> adjective. ['ragteɪl] **Chiefly US.** L20.
>
> **from RAG noun1 + TAIL noun1, perh. infl. by  ragtag and bobtail**.

It's mainly an adjective with the meaning,

[ragtail](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/11460/Ragtail): disorganized; untidy; disreputable.

Answer (score 0):

It is from the French saying 'trois tondus et un pelé' translated to 'ragtail and bobtail'

> **tondu**  m. shaveling, monk; trois tondus et un pelé, ragtail and
> bobtail -International French-English and English-French

Pelé is a skin.

> A **[shaveling](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/286283/shaveling)** is a tonsured clergyman : priest usually used
> disparagingly 2.  stripling or (not still a boy but not a man)

Both terms are related to an annoyance